# Macros inside ConTeXt reference labels

Tags: context

I want to automatically generate enumerated labels for enumerations in ConTeXt. However, I've tried the following and failed:

```
\definecounter[lol]
\incrementcounter[lol]\decrementcounter[lol]
\starttext
\incrementcounter[lol]
\placeformula[thm{\getnumber[lol]}]
\startformula
x^2+y^2=z^2
\stopformula
\placeformula[notatheorem]
\startformula
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\stopformula
\incrementcounter[lol]
\placeformula[thm{\getnumber[lol]}]
\startformula
\varphi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
\stopformula
I want to reference \in[thm1], \in[thm2] and \in[notatheorem]. Is that possible?
\stoptext
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can refer to the counter in a way which works in references with the `\rawcountervalue` command there is a simpler counter mechanism which works without problem in your case.

I modified your example to use the `\newcounter` mechanism where you can access the value as argument for other commands without problems. The mechanism uses three main commands:

- `\newcounter\...`

  - Create a new counter with the start value `0`.
  - Reset the value of the counter because there is no dedicated reset command.
- `\increment\...`

  - Increment the value of the counter by `1`.
  - When you use braces as argument to the command you increment the counter by a specified amount, e.g. `\increment(\...,3)` increases the counter by `3`.
- `\decrement\...`

  - Decrement the counter value by `1`
  - When you use braces as argument to the command you decrease the counter by a specified amount, e.g. `\decrement(\...,2)` decreases the counter by `2`.

---

```
\newcounter\LolCounter
%\increment\LolCounter
%\decrement\LolCounter

\starttext

\increment\LolCounter
\startplaceformula[reference={thm\LolCounter}]
    \startformula
        x^2+y^2=z^2
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\startplaceformula[reference={notatheorem}]
    \startformula
        e^{i\pi}+1=0
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

\increment\LolCounter
\startplaceformula[reference={thm\LolCounter}]
    \startformula
        \varphi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}
    \stopformula
\stopplaceformula

I want to reference \in[thm1], \in[thm2] and \in[notatheorem]. Is that possible?

\stoptext
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!